# Rewriting of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, infinitesimals

Consider the complex number $z = \sqrt{X+i\delta}$, with $0< \delta \ll 1$ and $X$ may be negative or positive.

I would like to reexpress this in the form $z= a+ i\delta$ where $a$ is positive.
If $X>0$, then $z = \sqrt{X(1+ i\delta/X)} = \sqrt{X} + i \delta$. What about the case  $X<0$? In particular, I'd like to understand if the sign of the imaginary part changes there.

To give context, I was considering an equation of the form $$\tilde{x_0} = 1-\sqrt{X+i\delta},$$ and I’d like to write it in the form $$\tilde{x_0} = x_0 \pm i \delta.$$ That is, extract the imaginary part. I need to do this to do some analytic continuation.  Here, $x_0$ is an analytic function.

Answer (score 3):

Square root of a complex number is a multi-valued function, you get 2 complex numbers normally (unless you're taking square root of zero).

> I would like to reexpress this in the form $z=a+iδ$ where a is positive.

I don't think it's a matter of what we want but what it is. Your delta is already positive, you cannot change that. So you cannot impose restrictions on the $a$. It is what it is.

Also, if you square this number $\sqrt{X} + i \delta$ I don't think you get the original number $X + i \delta$, do you? So I don't think this is the right way of taking the square root. I usually go through polar coordinates when taking square root of a complex number (using DeMoivre's theorem).

Finally, see this for a general formula which involves
just the algebraic form of the complex number:
[Square root of a complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Square_root)

Comment: Thank you. Please see my edits where I have better clarified my problem. I didn’t mean to say I wanted to take the square root, only somehow extract the imaginary part based on the fact Delta is infinitesimal.